# TypeScript: How to pass type information from parent to child?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given the following `Form` and its (uncontrolled) `Input` children:

```
<Form initialValues={{ firstName: "", lastName: "", age: "" }}>
  <Input label="First name" name="firstName" />
  <Input label="Last name" name="lastName" />
  <Input label="Age" name="age" />
</Form>
```

I'd like the `Input`'s `name` prop to be of type `"firstName" | "lastName" | "age"`. This type should be derived from the `Form`'s `initialValues`.

What's the cleanest way to achieve this?

---

**Note:** In the general case, form input components should be tree-shakeable.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use a loop to create the three Inputs instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Why not simply use controlled Inputs? Store their value in their parent's state, pass these values to them using a "value" field, and update the parent's state when using the Input with the onChange callback.

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/typed-react-children you can find some workarounds

Answer (score 8):

This piece of information cannot be automatically inferred. You'll have to manually provide the type one way or another. And ad-hoc solution would be like:

```
function App() {
  const initialValues = {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',
    age: 'string',
  }

  const MyInput: React.FC<{ label: string, name: keyof typeof initialValues }> = Input
  return <Form initialValues={initialValues}>
    <MyInput label="First name" name="firstNameWRONG" /> // error
    <MyInput label="Last name" name="lastName" />
    <MyInput label="Age" name="age" />
  </Form>
}
```

---

I'd like to talk about why it's impossible.

#### 1. Component declares its own protocol

I guess your mind model is to see child component as a "argument" to parent component, so it's reasonable to pose some kind of "requirement" from parent to child.

I wouldn't say such point of view is totally wrong, cus in practice parent-child component could be written in a coupling fashion, but it's not idiomatic in react.

Ideally, a react component should announce its own "protocol" through `props type`. You may think of a component as a "service", it's the responsibility of the **service consumer** to comply with the protocol, not the other way around.

#### 2. Limitation in TS type system

Transpiled to JS, such structure becomes:

```js
parentElement = React.createElement(Parent, parentProps,
  (childElement = React.createElement(Child, childProps))
)
```

First, if any type error were to be raised, it should be raise by the `parentElement` line, not `childElement`. What is violated is the protocol of parent component, which states "child component's `name` should be `keyof initValue`". And such verification is done by `React.createElement` function against its argument.

Second, from type system point of view, if we were able to infer `childProps`'s type from `parentProps`, then the resolution process should goes like:

```
1. let `Parent` be generic type of form
   Component<T, E<_>> = (props: { initValues: T, children: E<keyof T> }) => Element<any>
2. let `Child` be generic type of form
   Component<K> = (props: { name: K }) => Element<K>
3. from `childElement = React.createElement(Child, childProps))`
   we know `childElement` is type `Element<string>`
4. from `parentElement = React.createElement(Parent, parentProps, childElement)`
   we know about `T` and `E = Element` and `_ = keyof T`
5. now we need to allow prioritze `E<_>` rule over `Element<string>`, thus override `childElement` from `Element<string>` to `Element<keyof T>`
```

For such type system to work, we need to both support higher-kinded type parameter `E<_>` and also some sort of precedence of type operation.

Effectively we need to specify that `childElement` must not be resolved yet, but remain at a pending state of `Element<_>`, and then let the next resolution step to fill-in `_` part.

Plus, we don't mean anything like,

```
Element<T>.fill(arg: T)
```

But we mean,

```
fill<T>(arg0: T, arg1: Element<T>)
```

AFAIK, there's never a type system support such behavior, not to mention that TS doesn't even support higher-kinded type to begin with.

—-

#### Update

I think it’s worth mentioning that, it’s theoretically possible to raise type error from `Form` about `name` prop of `Input` not complying with protocol. However it cannot be done with JSX, only possible through `React.createElement`.

This is due to TS assigns all JSX created elements the special builtin interface `JSX.Element`. And react has augmented it to extend `React.ReactElement<any, any>`. The `any` thing effectively max out the `props` protocol of all elements, making any restriction impossible.

I tried to find workaround but unfortunately nothing found. The best you can get is what suggested in [the link](https://catchts.com/typed-react-children) provided in comment.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how your input is defined but i would create a type of formname and an interface for your input component using the formname type

```js
type FormName = "firstName" | "lastName" | "age";

interface InputProps {
  name: FormName
}
//or
interface InputProps {
  name: "firstName" | "lastName" | "age"
}

const Input: FC<InputProps> = (props): JSX.Element => {
   <input {...props}><input/>
};
```

Comment: The question mentions a `Form` that drives the type. Your answer doesn't make much sense since I don't see a `Form` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `keyof`

```
type initialValues = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: string
}

type inputName = keyof initialValues;

let age: inputName = "age"; //valid
let middleName: inputName = "middleName"; //invalid
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgdjYMCGAbAamgrhAzlAXigG8BYAKCigDMYAnXYAOWQFsIAuKRu+AcwDcFKqmSMW7Lj35DKUZH07dgvOHwoBfChVCRYcMFmZtoRANYQQAe2r7EKDNjyyKqCMHmKu8Q8faEoACIFCEDZNw9WGAATaLcJJR8jBIDAqNj4kzCgA

Edit: I feel like I'm missing something, but here's a code sandbox kind of showing how I would implement it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-monad-zo0p5?file=/src/App.tsx

Is something like that not possible? Is `Form` and `Input` being provided by a third party module?

Comment: You're missing a key point. How would the `Input` be able to do `keyof` on the `initialValues` passed to the parent `Form`?

Answer (score 0):

You just here need to restrict the prop `name` of your `Input` component and it can be achieved like that:

```js
export type InputName = "firstName" | "lastName" | "age"

export interface InputProps {
  name: InputName
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = (props) => {
  const { name } = props
  // ...
}
```

However that means that each `Input` in your app should have one these names, and I'm pretty sure that this is not what you want.

To be sure that each `Input` in a specific `Form` component have one of these name, you will need to define a new custom component that will extend the default behaviour:

**SpecificForm.tsx**

```js
import Form from 'components/Form'
import Input, { InputProps } from 'components/Input'

export type SpecificInputName = "firstName" | "lastName" | "age"
export interface SpecificInputProps extends InputProps {
  name: InputName
}
export type SpecificFormComponent = React.FC & { Input: React.FC<SpecificInputProps> }

const SpecificForm: SpecificFormComponent = (props) => {
  return <Form {...props}>{props.children}</Form>
}

const SpecificInput: React.FC<SpecificInputProps> = (props) => {
  return <Input {...props} />
}

SpecificForm.Input = SpecificInput

export default SpecificForm
```

Then you can consume it just like that:

```js
import Form from './components/SpecificForm'

<Form initialValues={{ firstName: "", lastName: "", age: "" }}>
  <Form.Input label="First name" name="firstName" />
  <Form.Input label="Last name" name="lastName" />
  <Form.Input label="Age" name="age" />
</Form>
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that form components won't be tree-shakeable. Imagine you have 10 different form input components like `Input`, `Select`, `RadioGroup`, etc. If a user creates a simple form with 2 `Input` fields, they should include only the `Form` and the `Input` component in their bundle. With your pproach, all 10 components will be included since they all defined on the `Form`.

Comment: You are right and that's why this component need to be a specific one (like `LoginForm`) that you are sure to consume (there is no reason to create it if you don't consume it).